# MongoDB, Doctrine 2 & Reference One-To-Many

Tags: php, mongodb, reference, doctrine, one-to-many

is regarding an association One-To-Many in the same table, but in MongoDB.

```
class Component
{
    ...
     /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(
     *   discriminatorMap={
     *     "component"="Component"
     *   },
     *   inversedBy="components.id",
     *   cascade={"persist", "remove", "refresh", "merge"}
     * )
     * 
     */
    protected $components;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->components = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add components
     *
     * @param $component
     */
    public function addComponents(Component $component)
    {
        if(!$this->components->contains($component)){
            $this->components->add($component);
        }   
    }
    ...
}
```

This associates the components me no problem, I look at the collection and actually associates me, but when I try to regain the components, $ this->components is not an ArrayCollection, but a Object Component

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved ...

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Component", inversedBy="children", cascade={"all"})
 */
public $parent;

/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Component", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"all"})
 */
public $children;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->children = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

public function addChild(component $child)
{
    if(!$this->children->contains($child)){
        $child->parent = $this;
        $this->children->add($child);
    }
}

/**
 * Get children
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $children
 */
public function getComponents()
{
    return $this->children;
}
```